# CSS Background Border Style and Position

Tags: html, css

How to get the following red boxes as background using only css and no images?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css pseudo class :after to generate content. Where .element is a class you add to each item

```
.element {
position:relative
}

.element:after {
background-color:red;
content:'';
height:30px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:10px;
width:10px;
z-index:10
}
```

Comment: You should use two colons: `::after`. Also note that his content is LTR, so maybe one needs to use `::before` instead?

Comment: should note that this does not work on 1e7 ( but we are not looking into that )

Comment: @ANeves - IE8 doesn't recognize double colon though? Can you clarify why after doesnt work but before does?

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh - This solution will not work in IE7. Depending on how many users you have using < IE 8 you may want to find a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
&nbsp;<span style="background-color: Red">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
```